# Возможно ли передать указатель в функцию, а в самой функции создать массив на который будет указывать указатель?

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы

Я хотел передать указатель int в функцию и там создать массив. Но при выполнении если int *arr присвоить NULL, то происходит Segmentation fault. Если int *arr присвоить new int[0], то массив в функции вроде как создается, но значения не присваиваются и выводит `0 0 0` вместо `1 2 3`

```c
void makeArr(int *arr)
{
  arr = new array[3];
  arr[0] = 1; arr[1] = 2; arr[2] = 3;
}

int main()
{
   int *arr = NULL // также пробовал int *arr = new int[0];
   makeArr(arr);
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     cout << arr[i] << " ";

   delete[]arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметры функции являются локальными переменными функции, которые инициализируются аргументами при вызове функции и прекращают свое существование при выходе из функции.

Поэтому если хотите, чтобы функция изменяла именно исходные аргументы, то их следует передавать либо через указатель на них, либо объявлять параметры как ссылочные типы. Например,

```
void makeArr(int **arr)
{
  *arr = new int[3];
  ( *arr )[0] = 1; ( *arr )[1] = 2; ( *arr )[2] = 3;
}
```

И вызывать функцию как

```
makeArr( &arr );
```

Или

```
void makeArr(int * &arr)
{
  arr = new int[3];
  arr[0] = 1; arr[1] = 2; arr[2] = 3;
}
```

И вызывать функцию как

```
makeArr( arr );
```

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

void makeArr( int **arr )
{
    *arr = new int[3];
    ( *arr )[0] = 1; ( *arr )[1] = 2; ( *arr )[2] = 3;
}

void makeArr( int * &arr )
{
    arr = new int[3];
    arr[0] = 3; arr[1] = 2; arr[2] = 1;
}

int main() 
{
    int *arr = nullptr;

    makeArr( &arr );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    delete []arr;

    makeArr( arr );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    delete []arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
1 2 3 
3 2 1
```

Comment: А можно сделать то же с просто указателем. То есть, если передать в функцию указатель.

Comment: @dreamIIx В этом случае используйте ссылочный тип параметра, как показано во втором примере функции.

Comment: Можно вместо  `arr[0] = 3; arr[1] = 2; arr[2] = 1;`, инициализировать при выделении `... = new int[3]{3,2,1};`